# Cython: 'PyxImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to integrate a Cython module into my project and I'm having trouble getting it to compile correctly. I have traced my problem to this minimal example:

Say I have two files `a.py` and `b.pyx` located in the same directory, if I then do the following in `a.py`:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import b
```

Then everything works fine, `b.pyx` is compiled and imported successfully.

But if I instead do this in `a.py`, assuming that `a.py` and `b.pyx` are located in `dir1/dir2`:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import dir1.dir2.b
```

(which is somewhat nonsensical in this example but illustrates what's preventing me from importing a from elsewhere in my module hierarchy), I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 888, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'PyxImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'
```

Is this expected behaviour or is something wrong with my installation? (I'm on Windows 10)

NOTE: there is another question with a very similar title on SO which does not answer my question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message (though not necessarily the same path situation) and it was resolved by upgrading Cython from 0.28.5 to 0.29.